# JavaFX how to set keyboard language to Arabic while focus in TextField

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, arabic

- JavaFX how to set keyboard language to Arabic while focus in `TextField`.
- I use this code in swing but not work in JavaFX with replacing `JTextField` to `TextField`.

```
public void Arabe(JTextField txt) {
    txt.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(new Locale("ar","EG"));
    txt.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);  
}
```

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions, please

Comment: just to check if I understand you correctyl: you want to localized one (or several) instances of nodes/controls differently from the rest of the ui?

Comment: @keopatra i need to set defualt keyboard language to arabic while foucused on text field